# Tcl - How to get the list of all possible sub-commands/switches for a given tcl command (including user defined commands)

Tags: tcl

For a given tcl user-defined command (for instance, "user_command -switch_A  -switch_B") I would like to get all the possible sub-commands/switches to be used with that command as a list.
Below is an example of the tcl regexp switches available:
[Regexp valid switches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz29L.png)

I would like to use it to compare "implemented and public sub-commands/switches VS documented and public sub-commands/switches" for a given program.

I can get the available commands from "info commands" command, but I'm struggling to get possible valid sub-commands/switches for a given command.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get options programmatically. You'll have to go to the documentation or the source code.

Comment: Intentionally put an invalid option and get the error message. For example, "lsort -xxx xxx" returns:
bad option "-xxx": must be -ascii, -command, -decreasing, ...
"glob -xxx" returns:
bad option "-xxx": must be -directory, -join, -nocomplain, ...

Answer (score 2):

The normal way is to use a deliberately wrong option name (such as `-!`) and to catch and parse the result.

```
proc listOptions args {
    try {
        {*}$args -!
    } on error msg {
        if {[regexp {should be one of (.*)} $msg -> items]} {
            return [string map {{, or } { } , {}} $items]
        }
    }
    error "no option list from $args"
}

puts [listOptions chan configure stdout]
```

Answer (score 1):

To find subcommands for commands that are implemented as `namespace ensemble`s, you can do:

```
set cmd "string"
set map [namespace ensemble configure $cmd -map]
dict keys $map
# => bytelength cat compare equal first index is last length map match range repeat replace reverse tolower toupper totitle trim trimleft trimright wordend wordstart
```

Comment: Most things with subcommands are either ensembles or objects now. Standard ensembles have the advantage of being possible to bytecode compile into, whereas objects are quite a bit more flexible (because there's a class system with dynamic dispatch).